# Perl XML:DOM::Parser NoExpand still expanding entities

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I am using the `XML::DOM::Parser` library to read an XML file, do some minor adjustments and dump it back out again.  There are some encoded entities in the file and I want to preserve them in their encoded form.  I've tried using the NoExpand option for the parser but it still seems to expand entities.  The following is a minimal example of the problem:

```
use XML::DOM;
my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser(NoExpand => 1);
my $doc = $parser->parse('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MyTest Content="&#13;"/>');
print $doc->toString;
```

The output is the following (note the entity has been expanded):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><MyTest Content="^M"/>
```

I'm using ActiveState Perl 5.16.3.1603 with XML::DOM 1.44 and XML::Parser 2.41

Is there any way of getting `NoExpand` to not expand that I've missed?

Comment: Can you use another `xml` parser?

Comment: It's not really my script.  I was just trying to debug the issue for a colleague.  I believe that the 'minor adjustments' are actually quite substantial and tied to the XML::DOM library.  Also, there is a suite of scripts that will also have the same issue and be quite time consuming to replace the parser for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes a bit of documentation diving. As you can see in the documentation for [XML::DOM::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~enno/libxml-enno-1.02/lib/XML/DOM/Parser.pod):

The ***XML::Parser*** NoExpand option is more or less supported

Reviewing the relevant documentation for [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/XML-Parser-2.41/Parser.pm#METHODS)

This has no effect if a default handler has not been registered, and it has no effect on the expansion of entity references **inside attribute values**.

So, if this feature in this parser is going to work for you at all, it's not going to work for attribute values. If it really matters to you:

- Try a different XML parser
- File a bug or a patch with Enno Derksen, the author of XML::Parser.